# Are there specific laws or stringencies regarding a "Chabad mikve"

Tags: chabad, mikvah-ritual-bath

I have been informed of an ongoing fundraising effort for a "Chabad mikve". Are there specific halachic stringencies (*chumrot*) regarding such a mikve according to Chabad? Would Chabad women not be able to use a regular kosher mikve?

A Chabad *shaliach* explicitly told me "there is no Chabad mikve for women in that city" but didn't answer when I asked about the halachic rationale for such a mikve.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Chabadnikim prefer a Bor Al Gabei Bor setup [because a rebbi of theirs came up with it as a chumra and for a few years it was a symbol of chasidic/mitnagdic fighting so it became overly important to people who still define themselves by that fight]

Comment: The law is that since everyone has to use the mikva and one cant have a different mikva for everyone, therefore the mikva has to be kosher for everyone. One is not allowed to have a mikva in a town where chabad women cant use it.

Comment: Todays modern mikvas use drawn up well water. Since there is no shortage of water the chabad chumra is not really necessary.

Comment: @patient your first comment is interesting. I know for a fact that there are cities where the mikve is not Chabad-compliant. Wonder if there is a source for the law you quote. Thanks.

Comment: @mbloch If you want to review all of the takanot of the Rebbes of Chabad concerning mikvah construction this sefer is an excellent source. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=23763&st=&pgnum=1